# hash of array in objective-c, how?

Tags: objective-c, data-structures

How is a hash of integer array can be represented in objective-c? Here is the ruby hash as an example:

```
hi_scores = { "John" => [1, 1000],
              "Mary" => [2, 8000],
              "Bob"  => [5, 2000] }
```

such that can be accessed by:

```
puts hi_scores["Mary"][1]
=> 8000
```

hopefully easy to serialize too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDictionary * highScores = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1000], nil], @"John",
                                                                       [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:8000], nil], @"Mary",
                                                                       [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2000], nil], @"Bob", nil];

NSLog(@"%@", [[highScores objectForKey:@"Mary"] objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a data structure called a [map / associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

Take a look at this question:
[HashTables in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474316/hashtables-in-cocoa)